# fancyBox 3 modal page shift on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

When modal overflow occours, the modal shifts out of the page. Erasing the element `.fancybox-slide:before` makes the modal return to the top of the screen, but without this element, the modal cannot be centered.

The modal is created by:

```
$().fancybox({
    selector: '.btn',
    // Shortcut to make content "modal" - disable keyboard navigtion, hide buttons, etc
    modal : true,
    touch : {
        vertical : false,  // Allow to drag content vertically
        momentum : false   // Continue movement after releasing mouse/touch when panning
    },
});
```

And the HTML is:

```
<a class="btn" data-fancybox data-type="ajax" data-src="#" href="javascript:;">Text</a>
```

---

If I set the content inside `.fancybox-slide` to `max-width: 100%`, everything works fine, but with a x-scrollbar  inside the content view.

Comment: Yes, that is how it works. So, is there any question you want to ask?

Comment: There's could be a wrapper for this kinda content with a `max-width: 100%` rule, so new users will not have to figure out what is happening.

Comment: That additional wrapper would bring more problems.

Comment: The one I had to use is doing its job very well, what could be the problems?